# Display Facebook Group Wall Feed on Website

Tags: php, facebook

I've been scouring the web for weeks on how to display a *Facebook Group* Wall Feed on a website.  I've only uncovered one piece of `php` code that seems to work. The problem is this code works on my server, but not the server where the *Facebook Group* Wall feed will be displayed live.  I can provide the code if need be.  Any solutions using `php` or any other method would be appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the code.

```css
.events {
text-align:left;
font-size:.8em
 
}

#entries {
text-align:left 
}

.event-month {
font-size:1.0em 
}
```

```html
 <?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 
$limit = 5;
 
$group_id = '17906888936';
$url1 = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$group_id;
$des = json_decode(file_get_contents($url1));
 
$url2 = "https://graph.facebook.com/{$group_id}/feed?access_token=321965427969215|0mLC-FGb6Tbk4VAoqTFYlCHgxw4";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url2));
?> 
<div style="overflow:auto;height:300px">
 <div style="margin-bottom:20px">
 <a href='http://www.facebook.com/home.php?sk=group_<?=$group_id?>&ap=1'>
<?=$des->name?></a>
 <div style="width:90%; margin: 5px;">
 <?=$des->description?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?
 $counter = 0;
  
 foreach($data->data as $d) {
 if($counter==$limit)
 break;
 ?>
 <div style="margin-bottom:20px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-bottom-style:solid;border-bottom-color:#EEE">
 <div>
 <a href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>">
    <img style="float:left;padding-right:10px" border="0" alt="<?=$d->from->name?>" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$d->from->id?>/picture"/>
 </a>
 </div>
 <div>
 <span style="font-weight:bold"><a href="http://facebook.com/profile.php?id=<?=$d->from->id?>">
<?=$d->from->name?></a></span><br/>
 <span style="color: #999999;">on<?=date('F j, Y H:i',strtotime($d->created_time))?></span>
 <br/>
 <?=$d->message?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?
 $counter++;
 }
 ?>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yes, it would be very beneficial to show us the code that you have done so far.

Comment: I've added code to my original post.  As I previously mentioned it works here  http://chrismcurtis.com/dev/wwic/ but not here http://www.iowalum.com/westernwashington/  Thank you in advance.